# Can't use Zyxel Wifi dongle with ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 13.10

I have some issue to have Wifi working properly on my pc. I'm using a Wifi Dongle from Zyxel, type NWD2205, Region : ETSI. Ubuntu is 13.10.
I used this dongle on windows and it worked OK with strong signal. Now with ubuntu I have a very random behavior.
Some time the dongle works OK and I can access Internet (right now for example) and after a few minutes, I lost the connection. After that, sometime the connection is up again and sometimes I have to disable - enable wifi and/or networking a few time and/or unplug - replug the dongle to get it to work again.

I've searched through some topic on wifi but I was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Please let me know what kind of info you need ? How can I know the current driver installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up yesterday and bought a Edimax EW-7711UAn. Works perfectly out-of-the-box !